# Math usage: the affine n-space vs affine n-space

Tags: word-choice, definite-articles

In the book *Algebraic Geometry* by Robin Hartshorne (and many other publications), he writes

> We define affine n-space over a field to be the set [...]

and

> Our next objective is to show that projective n-space has an open covering [...]

My question is what might be the justification of removing the article "the" before "affine n-space"? Why would he not say "the affine n-space" instead?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419147/using-the-with-mathematical-properties . The short answer is that articles can be omitted in mathematical writing for the sake of brevity. My math mind reads "we define affine n-space" as defining a general concept; I'd only expect an article if a specific and previously defined object were being discussed.

Comment: Is it a matter of redundancy? The sample sentences are clear and easy to understand.

Comment: You're better off asking a mathematician, because in English grammar it depends on whether there is one or many affine n-spaces, and whether they follow inevitably or are chosen arbitrarily. (Not that mathematicians are typically experts in English grammar.)